# container start run a script

Tags: docker, cakephp-2.x, kitematic

I want to have a script that runs in my docker container at every start/restart. It should run the bash of the container with:

```
cd app
Console/cake schema update
```

and

```
Console/cake migration
```

I tired to run a process or write something in my dockerfile, but that all doesnt work for me. I also read the "Run multiple services in a container" from docker, but i didnt find a solution.

COPY starter.sh /etc/init.d/starter.sh

```
RUN chmod +x /etc/init.d/starter.sh
RUN chmod 755 /etc/init.d/starter.sh
RUN update-rc.d starter defaults 10
RUN /etc/init.d/starter.sh
```

in my starter.sh is some test code like

```
RUN mkdir /var/www/hello
```

that i know if it works

Comment: what script do you want to run? did you try with entrypoint or CMD command?

Comment: yes but it didnt work for me because my container stopped after the script

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) in `dockerfile`

Add these lines in `dockerfile`

```
COPY starter.sh /opt/starter.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/starter.sh"]
```

**Update:**

If you want to run apache web server then add these lines

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/path/to/apache2"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

This will run `apache2` as first process inside container in daemon mode.

Comment: but how can i run bash in my script? And if i do it like you said it runs the script and end the process of apache. the container is stopped

Comment: provide contents of `starter.sh` then only I can answer it.

Comment: if your container stopped after the script then the problem is probably in the script. Can you provide content of this script? You can also try to execute commands from your script in container to see which command is problematic

Comment: i run only mkdir. Can i start the apache process after it? with apache2 -D FOREGROUND

Comment: the update code in the starter.sh or in the dockerfile after the script runs?

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer. It explains how to run apache in background as daemon process.

Comment: Update both the dockerifle and starter.sh

Comment: i mean where can i put the COPY starter.sh /opt/starter.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/starter.sh"] code and where the other code and in which order? the first i think in the dockerfile and the sec too or in the starter.sh?

Comment: The `starter.sh` script needs to end with the line `exec "$@"`, which will make it run the `CMD`.

Comment: @andre.hey you should put those lines in your `dockerfile`. If you're still confused please provide whatever `dockerfile` or `starter.sh` file contents.